# How to change listening port in nameko?

Tags: nameko

Has anyone used [nameko](https://github.com/onefinestay/nameko) before?

In its documentation, I can't find anything about changing listening port:
http://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built_in_extensions.html#http-get-post

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As (eventually) replied on the [gh issue](https://github.com/onefinestay/nameko/issues/364):

You need to use a config file with the key `WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS`:

```
# config.yaml
AMQP_URI: amqp://guest:guest@localhost
WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0:8888
```

Then

```
$ nameko run --config config.yaml your_service_module
```

[Official Reference](http://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#running-a-service)

Comment: oops, I should have answered this myself.